# API Structure with Django Rest Framework

Tags: api, django-rest-framework

I'm beginner in API building and would like to doublecheck if my structure is correct.

1) Endpoint /articles. GET - retrieve all articles. POST - add new article - is that correct?

2) Endpoint /profile. GET - retrieve profile info authorized user. PUT - update profile info  - is that correct?

3) Endpoint /profile/posts. GET - retrieve all articles authorized user. Is that correct or maybe better union Endpoint 2) and Endpoint 3) ?

4) Endpoint /articles/ GET - retrieve article. PUT - update article. Is that correct?

Maybe, is there any general recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint structure shouldn't really depend on whether the user is authorized or not. So i don't see a difference between 3 and 1. If you want to retrieve articles of a given user, then in REST structure, it should be `/profile/<profile_id>/articles`. If you want to retrieve articles for the currently logged in user without providing the id, then you could have something like `/articles/mine/`. This can be implemented by adding a custom `mine` action to the articles viewset.

And what is the difference between the first endpoint and 4th? just the trailing slash? If that is meant to be a detail endpoint according to your description, then it should be `/article/<article_id>`

Comment: Yes there was a typo. 4) should be as you wrote.